# Style of Slideshow

Tags: stylesheet, user-interface

So I am giving my first shot at making a Mma slideshow. But I am finding difficult to change the formatting of Sections and others in the slideshow.

I can change the style of Sections in the Working environment through the Format > Edit Stylesheet menu. Yet, even when I change the environment to Slideshow (via Format > Screen Environment > Slideshow), and then edit the stylesheet I see no results.

Here is what I see in the stylesheet editor when trying to change the style of the slideshow:

```
Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> FrontEnd`FileName[{"SlideShow"}, "Sapphire.nb", 
  CharacterEncoding -> "WindowsANSI"]]]

Cell[StyleData["Section"],
 FontFamily->"Calibri",
 FontSize->48,
 FontWeight->"Bold",
 FontSlant->"Plain",
 FontVariations->{"StrikeThrough"->False,
 "Underline"->False}]
```

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong? I tried changing the Font to Calibri and make it Bold, but when I start the presentation, none of this shows up.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is a comma missing after `CharacterEncoding -> "WindowsANSI"]]]`

Comment: Have you tried to toggle back the cell to the formated mode (ctrl+shift+E) and change to the Sideshow Environment?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, this was a manual copy of the two cells in the stylesheet editor, but there is no comma there. I have two separate cells there.

Spawn1701D, yes. Section still shows the same formatting as before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation:

```
  StyleData["style", "environment"]      represents the contents of a style definition
                                         cell in the style environment "environment"
```

So, you need to modify existing cell or add a new: `Cell[StyleData["Section", "SlideShow"], ...]`